# java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on (PhysicalConnection.java:2356)

Tags: java, oracle, websphere-7

My web application start doesn't present error, but when i run it, I have this error...

None of my colleagues can help me, some of you?

i'm using websphere 7 on eclipse rational and java 1.6.0

```
E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Errore servlet]-[action]: it.xxx.navigator.exception.NavigatorException: java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on
    at it.xxx.navigator.Navigator.throwException(Navigator.java:53)
    at it.xxx.navigator.Navigator.initialize(Navigator.java:217)
    at it.xxx.pensionis7.action.IndexAction.index(IndexAction.java:499)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)


Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2356)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2403)
    at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.commit(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:139)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.commit(WSJdbcConnection.java:1112)
    at it.xxx.navigator.dao.NavigatorConnection.commit(NavigatorConnection.java:46)
    at it.xxx.navigator.delegate.NavigatorBD.getDefinedApplications(NavigatorBD.java:78)
    at it.xxx.navigator.delegate.NavigatorDelegate.getDefinedApplications(NavigatorDelegate.java:33)
    at it.xxx.navigator.Navigator.initialize(Navigator.java:190)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Have you found the code that create this?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's JDBC driver throws an exception when trying to commit with`getAutoCommit() == true`.

So you either: use auto commit and do not call `commit()` at all (it'll be called automatically)

or

call `commit()` only when `getAutoCommit() == false`:

```java
if (!connection.getAutoCommit()) {
    connection.commit();
}
```

Comment: I don't have getAutoCommit if I serch it

Comment: @dav03ros, what do you do in `NavigatorConnection.commit()`?

Comment: Nothing cause navigator is an external jar

Comment: Then the problem is in that external jar. If you can not change it, the only solution I can suggest - disable auto commit mode (`connection.setAutoCommit(false)`) so that `connection.commit()` can be invoked inside `NavigatorConnection`.

Comment: Where can I disable this auto commit mode?

Comment: Since you're working on WebSphere, try this tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-set-auto-commit-websphere-application-server-connection